# Uploading data from Excel to SQL formatting date

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I am using VBA to upload data from and Excel file into SQL Server. The date column in the CSV as I get is in the "mm/dd/yy format". How do I format the date to be in the SQL Server format "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss:000" before I pass it to the query to insert the record?

I declare the variable

```
Dim InvoiceDate As Date
```

I get the value from the workbook

```
InvoiceDate = row.Cells(5).Value
```

I insert into the table

```
INSERT INTO table(InvoiceDate) VALUES (" & InvoiceDate & ")
```

I end up with this:

```
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Perhaps using `Format$`.

Comment: Why write your own script in VBA if there is an [Import and Export Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/start-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard) that is fully documented and [supports Microsoft Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-an-excel-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard)?

Comment: @BigBen is correct - `Format$(InvoiceDate,"YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss:000")` will do it.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman is correct but I suspect the `InvoiceDate` in the code is assigned the value of an empty cell!

Comment: @Sander I know there is an import wizard in SQL, however I am not letting users in there. The idea is for a one-button operation from Excel.

Comment: @Scott Holtzman Okay, I understand the formatting, but WHERE in the code does it go? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I added my own variable after getting the value from the Excel worksheet and before uploading to SQL:
`sDate = Format(InvoiceDate, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss:000")`